# How to implement customize list view for multiple screen size in android

Tags: android

I have tried customize list view for multiple screen size, but I couldn't achieve that. Can anybody tell me how to implement customize list view for multiple screen size in android? I have used dip in my layout. When I use dip, will it work? I have given the layout folder the name layout layout-small layout-large ,layout-xlarge.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hope this one will help you

http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/ListView.java?av=h

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/widget/ListView.java.htm

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/09/designing-for-android-tablets/